# Prove that a translate of a polynomial has roots without using FTA

Tags: polynomials

Let $F\in\mathbf C[Z]$ be a polynomial of degree $d$. Without using the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, is it true that there is some $u\in\mathbf C$ such that $F + u$ has $d$ roots (counted with multiplicity)?

Thanks!
Nicolás

Comment: What you mean by "without using the fundamental theorem of algebra"? What properties of $\mathbb{C}$ do you want to use? Certainly the claim will not be true over arbitrary fields.

Comment: The statement is a weak form of the FTA. I am wondering if there is a simpler proof of this statement, without proving the full FTA.

Comment: This seems quite unlikely to me. The proofs that I know of FTA show that a polynomial $F(Z)$ has one root $\alpha$. One then applies induction on degree to $F(Z)/(Z-\alpha)$. Now perhaps one can show simply that $F(Z)+u$ has a root $\alpha$, but then one needs to show that $(F(Z)+u)/(Z-\alpha)$ itself (rather than $(F(Z)+u)/(Z-\alpha)+v$) has a root.

Comment: Thanks for the answers!